# Helmholtz’s theorem and electrostatic charge density

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

According to Helmholtz’s theorem, the electric charge density has to go to to zero as r goes to infinity faster than 1/r^2 to be able to construct an electrostatic potential function, yet I don't understand how this applies to a chunk of charge in some region of space, regarding how fast its charge density does to zero. For instance, suppose I only have a small sphere of charge, how fast does does charge density go to zero as r goes to infinity?

Comment: Validity of the Helmholtz theorem isn't necessary for a potential function to exist. For example, consider electric potential of an infinite charged plane - a potential function $\phi(z) = C|z|$ exists and gives correctly electric field.

Comment: If you have a small sphere of charge, then charge density is zero outside that sphere, so it doesn't really "go to zero" as r goes to infinity, instead it *is* zero for $r>a$ for some $a$.

Comment: So whenever I have a density that is confined to some domain and suddenly ceases afterwards I can use the helmholtz's theorem? How is this implies from the statement of the theorem?

Comment: The Helmholtz theorem does not operate with or depend on the concept of charge density. It is valid for a general vector field in 3D space, provided the field obeys some conditions, like being smooth enough. In the case of sphere of charge, unless the charge is distributed in a too singular manner (point or line charges), the Helmholtz theorem should be applicable.